# How can I fetch products in Magento using an attribute's value, and not label

Tags: magento

```
$this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',array(
    "eq",'43') 
                                           )
                      );
```

This fetches the products of a certain manufacturer, based on the attribute's id, which is a number.

How can I modify this to get the products of a certain manufacturer (or attribute), but with the attribute's value, and not the id?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this ,
->addFieldToFilter(array(
        array('attribute'=>'manufacturer','eq'=>'ABC')

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $manufacturer_name = 'xyz';
    $product = NULL;
    $manufacturer_id = NULL;

    $manufacturers  = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product','manufacturer')->getSource()->getAllOptions(false,true);

    foreach($manufacturers as $m){
       if(strtolower($m['label']) == strtolower($manufacturer_name)){
          $manufacturer_id = $m['value'];
          continue;
       } 
    }

   if($manufacturer_id){
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('manufacturer', $manufacturer_id);  
   }

   print_r($product);
```